Az Cli for CosmosDb Restore set Minimum TLS Version
We got a policy that allows only CosmosDb with minimum TLS1.2.
I am trying to work on Disaster Recovery using Az Cli but the restore which creates a new CosmosDb account with default TLS1.0
Here is the Cli I tried with. Any other options to force the restore to be TLS1.2 and above?
az cosmosdb restore --target-database-account-name "<target-db-account-name>" --account-name "<account-name>" --restore-timestamp 2024-05-28T15:06:00+0000 --resource-group "<rgName>" --location "<location>" --public-network-access Disabled --disable-ttl True


I ended up using Bicep instead of Az cli which has the options to configure


Any other options to force the restore to be TLS1.2 and above?

After restoring the database, you can use the az cosmosdb update command with option --minimal-tls-version to set the minimum allowed TLS version.
Example:
resourceGroup="myresourcegroup"
dbName="mycosmosdbaccount"
minimalTlsVersion="Tls12"

az cosmosdb update -n $dbName -g $resourceGroup --minimal-tls-version $minimalTlsVersion


Thanks @Rui Jarimba, I have seen the update but the problem is I couldnt restore successfully to run az cosmosdb update
